# Pentaho does not execute procedure without paramters

Tags: oracle, jdbc, pentaho, pdi

Good afternoon everyone, I have a question. I'm making a procedure call in Pentaho but it has no parameters (it was done in oracle, native JDBC connection). This procedure does not appear in the list of procedures to be performed (Call DB Procedure component). Has anyone gone through something similar and know how to proceed?

I've tried to use other component like SQL Script, but using it there is no error and not processing.

Bellow prints, when I try to find the procedure it does not appear and If I put the name by myself, does not execute.

[Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIPVa.png)

[Call Procedure Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lt0o.png)

[Find window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kY6i.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Share your ETL process (at least in image). It will help to understand your question.

Comment: @Ahmmed I put some prints